# Is "the human cost of inaction is inefficient and even deadly" proper english

Tags: phrases, writing-style

This is taken from ["Streetfight: Handbook for an Urban Revolution"](https://books.google.com/books?id=rh7ZCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA28&lpg=PA28&dq=the%20human%20cost%20of%20inaction%20is%20inefficient%20and%20even%20deadly&source=bl&ots=QA0Ov93r7y&sig=2X4urZwgXtZ7GiklM4Y3qgBe4VM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwipt9iXkq_VAhUIhlQKHQbSDRkQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=the%20human%20cost%20of%20inaction%20is%20inefficient%20and%20even%20deadly&f=false):

> The human cost of inaction is inefficient and even deadly, but the political stakes for people who design and build city streets couldn't be lower.

I know that there is a phrase "deadly cost" but what I wonder is whether it is proper (or good writing style) to break phrase like that and say "cost is deadly". Second point, is I am not sure if it is proper English to write "cost is inefficient".

Comment: Well, I'd say 'cost *of* inaction', and 'inefficiency'. I think they're implying 'inaction is deadly', but the sentence is pretty strange.

Comment: @marcellothearcane sorry, original is "cost OF inaction"

Comment: It's a poor sentence.  Cost isn't inefficient or deadly.

Answer (score 1):

The 'costs' should be noun phrases: "The human costs of inaction are inefficiency and [potentially] even death, but..."